# Firefox + jQuery on OS X doesn't show errors thrown in AJAX handlers?

Tags: jquery, ajax, macos, firefox, xmlhttprequest

When an error occurs in a jQuery AJAX handler on Firefox + jQuery + OS X the error seems to be silently ignored.

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/bGuX9/

Chrome correctly reports both errors in the JavaScript console:

[image: error in Chrome]

But Firebug in Firefox only reports *one* error, even though two have been thrown (as evidenced by the “Throwing error: in ajax”):

[image: error in Firefox]

The above is Firefox 8 on OS X 10.6, but I've noticed the issue as far back as Firefox 3.5. Firefox on Windows (tested with 8) doesn't seem to be affected.

What's up with this? Is this a known issue?

A couple notes:

- I don't believe this is an issue with Firebug, as the error doesn't appear in Firefox's error console either.
- I know that I can use a `try/catch` block in my event handler and catch the error there, but that doesn't help me debug arbitrary code.

Comment: My "old" Firefox (7.0.1) on Win with Firebug 1.8.4 is throwing both errors.

Comment: I upgraded to Firefox 8 (Win) with same Firebug 1.8.4 and it's throwing both errors too.

Comment: Alright, after some testing, it appears to be a problem with *something* in my profile, because it works when running with a clean profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, it looks like this issue is caused by the Adblock Plus extension, as it only occurs when the extension is enabled.

A bug has been filed on the Adblock Plus forum: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8761